# HTA application and confirming the browser close

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need your help. I have an HTA appliecation and when I go to close the browser window using the [X] button in (IE 7) and I confirm the action using the code below, I get an error message saying: "object doesn't support this property or method"

I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

```
<body onbeforeunload="return promptonclose()">


function promptonclose()
    {
          if (confirm('Do you want to close this form?')){
                alert('you clicked OK');
          }else{
                alert('Cancelling form close');
                window.event.stopPropogation();
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE7 doesn't support `event.stopPropagation` yet. Only the `event.returnValue` can be used for `onbeforeunload` event. Note that the web browser will always display its own dialog box for the final decision, so script won't have full control to prevent the current window/tab from closing, and presenting a confirmation dialog (via `confirm`) won't be useful.

Using the `event.returnValue`, the script can only choose a custom message for the final web browser prompt dialog like this:

```
<body onbeforeunload=" window.event.returnValue='This form will be closed.'; ">
```